# Call by value result or something else

Tags: java, compiler-construction, operating-system, thread-safety, programming-languages

in Programming language course my professor take an example.

Suppose the following code:

```
int x=initialization();
Thread T1=new computethread(x);
Thread t2=new evaluatethread(x);
...
...
Thread t100=new evaluatethread(x);
```

threads `t1` to `t100` needs the initial value of variable `x` for their computation and `t1` need to change the `x`, which transfer of parameter for `computethread`, `evaluatethread` is preferred?

my professor say:

```
1) call by value result

2) call by ref
```

is preferred for sending x to `computethread`,  `evaluatethread`, why call by result or call by name or this order like   2) call by value result,     1) call by ref is not preferred?
why he conclude these are better?

Comment: Can you make the difference between `computethread` and `evaluatethread` clearer? Do you mean that for `computethread` `x` is an in/out parameter, while for `evaluatethread` its only an input?

Comment: he said, t1 to t100 need the initial value of x and t1 change the value of x. I think just computethread() change the value x and others not change.

Answer (score 2):

There's only *one* mode of transfer in Java: pass by value.

Primitives like int. double, boolean are obvious: the value is passed.

The same is true for objects on the heap, but the thing that is passed by value is the *reference* to that object.  The object itself is on the heap, not on the stack frame. There is no built in copy mechanism in Java like there is for C++.

You cannot change the value of the reference, but you can modify the state of the object it points to if it has mutable data exposed.

Comment: Dear duffymo, I couldn't understand how you verify my professor solutions?

Comment: @Dr.Jackson I think, duffymo says the question does not make much sense... because in Java, there is only way to pass variables. So giving two options looks strange to say the least.

Comment: I have no idea what your professor is thinking, but my answer is the correct one.  James Gosling explains here: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?JavaPassesByValue

Answer (score 0):

I think your professor may have used syntax that looks like Java for the sake of an example but, as others have noted, Java only supports pass by value. If, however, we are talking about a hypothetical language that simply has eerily similar syntax, then pass-by-value-result describes the desired semantics...

Under pass by value result, modifications to a parameter are only committed after the function has completed. Prior to the completion of the function, modifications only happen to a local copy.

To expound further, pass-by-value-result is roughly equivalent to providing all input parameters by value and returning an object that encapsulates the updated values of all the parameters. After the function is called, the variables in the caller are assigned these updated values. By contrast, in pass-by-value the updated values are ignored and discarded, and in pass-by-reference, the updates are immediately assigned back to the original source. So, to make this a little bit more concrete, let's consider this example:

```
add(x, value):
  print 'Called with: ' + x
  x = x + value
  print 'Modified x: ' + x

main():
  x = 0
  add(x, 3)
  add(x, 2)
  print 'Caller x: ' + x
```

Under pass-by-value, this would print:

```
Called with 0
Modified x: 3
Called with 0
Modified x: 2
Caller x: 0
```

... because the parameter is a copy within "add", and updates to this copy are not propagated back to the caller. Under pass-by-value-result, the output of this example would be:

```
Called with 0
Modified x: 0
Called with 3
Modified x: 3
Caller x: 5
```

... because, the "add" function is passed an immutable copy of "x", and writes to "x" are only propagated after the function exits (thus, within "add", subsequent attempts to read the value give the original value rather than the modified value). After the function has completed, however, the assigned value is returned/committed to the original variable. By contrast, pass-by-reference would output:

```
Called with 0
Modified x: 3
Called with 3
Modified x: 5
Caller x: 5
```

... because pass-by-reference passes the memory address of the variable "x" to the "add" function, and the "add" function immediately writes modifications back to this location.

Comment: why call by name or call by result are not preferred? would you please add a bit more detail /

Comment: you means because the computethread change value of x, and other threads need the initial value of x, we should choose pass by value result for computethread?

Comment: Pass-by-result is just shorthand for saying by-value-result, AFAIK. I've updated the answer to explain this more clearly. Pass-by-name is even more exotic and is more like how macros in C and C++ work. The main thing with pass-by-name is that the text of the parameter (including entire expressions) are substituted and lazily evaluated. It's better explained here: http://www.cs.sfu.ca/~cameron/Teaching/383/PassByName.html

Comment: @Dr.Jackson yes, that's correct. Since these need the initial value, using pass-by-value-result will make them see the original value, while still allowing the parameter to be updated by computethread.

Comment: and my last questions is 1) why for others use call by ref? 2)in pass by value result value of x changed after the thread is completed? thanks from your time. thanks. thanks again.

Comment: In this question, you wouldn't use pass-by-reference. You'd only use pass-by-value-result. You use pass-by-reference in other scenarios where you want to commit the modification immediately. Note that, in multithreading scenarios, using pass-by-reference also requires that reads/writes of the reference are synchronized (or that the item being written is volatile and written atomically) to ensure that reads do not see the value in an invalid, partially written state.

Comment: Dear @Michael, would you please describe: "multithreading scenarios, using pass-by-reference also requires that reads/writes of the reference are synchronized (or that the item being written is volatile and written atomically) to ensure that reads do not see the value in an invalid, partially written state"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63272/discussion-between-michael-aaron-safyan-and-dr-jackson).

Answer (score 0):

If the assumption I made is right, which I think is likely and ignoring the language which has nothing to with the question IMO.

The desired behaviour is to have one thread that will modify `x`, and 99 others that will just perform some computations on its initial value.

Remember that threads share the same address space. So to avoid interference between threads you want them to operate on local copies of the argument. So call by reference is out of question (*there is a "special" case mentioned below*).

Now since `evaluatethread`s do not need to return anything, so they can just use call-by-value. `computethread` needs to modify the value, so `call-by-value-return` is needed.

Also note that all variations that exclude the interference are also valid. For example, if you `pass-by-reference` only to `t1`, it is fine, because no other threads will directly touch `x`. But this is ok only if you can guarantee that it is the only thread. Generally I would not call it a safe assumption.

Call-by-name is not good, because if `computethread` modifies `x` before `evaluatethread` will need its value, it won't get `x` after initialization but the updated one.

Comment: Dear @Luk, call by value return is call by value result?

Comment: maybe the speed of call by ref is high, and computethread instead of call by values, use call by ref?

Comment: [Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_copy-restore): "*Call-by-copy-restore, copy-in copy-out, call-by-value-result or call-by-value-return (as termed in the Fortran community) is a special case of call-by-reference where the provided reference is unique to the caller.*", so I guess it is the same. call by value makes a copy, while call by reference does not. Making copy can be expensive. This is why const reference was introduced in c++. To contract non-modification, but skip the copy overhead of passing by value.

Comment: But ... in this case there is no advantage, references usually have size of the integer (at least in "close-to-machine" languages), even if not, they should not be big enough to justify (non-const) reference forsaking the safety. Of course that is my opinion.

Comment: with you answer I sure that for computethread we use call by value result but for evaluatethreads I have doubt.